# Subgradient chain rule

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, convex-optimization, matrix-analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose $$F:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R},\; F(x)=\mathrm{max}_\mathrm{eig}(C-\mbox{diag}(x)).$$
I am trying to find a subgradient of $F$ at $x_0$. A subgradient of $\mathrm{max}_\mathrm{eig}$ is given by $xx^T$ where $x$ is an eigenvector with the largest eigenvalue. However, when I try to find a subgradient of the diagonal map $\mbox{diag}$ I realize the subgradient, just like its gradient, is not a matrix but a tensor. How should I proceed with this derivation?

Comment: This tensor times the matrix $xx^T$ gives a vector and this is a subgradient, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @Dirk Yes I would suspect so, from the multidimensional chain rule, is there a nice way to carry out the derivation then?